# Do they mean the same "i got one" or "i got it"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am wondering to see if they mean the same or different.

> "Did you get one of the papers?" "Yes I got **one**" or "yes I got **it**"
>
> "I missed **one** event day" or " I missed **an** event today"
>
> "Can I have **one** hamburger, please" or "Can I have **a** hamburger, please"

Answer (score 1):

```
"Did you get one of the papers?" "Yes I got one" or "yes I got it"
```

Here the question is specifically about any one of papers(among all the papers). Hence `"Yes I got one"` will be more perfect that `"Yes I got it"`, since `it` referring to a particular paper but `One` referring to any one among the all papers.

```
"I missed one event day" or " I missed an event today"

"Can I have one hamburger, please" or "Can I have a hamburger, please"
```

In both the above examples using `One` and `An` will give same meaning and using `An/A` based on the Vowels will be more perfect than simply using `an`.

Answer (score 0):

We use *a/an* to talk about **one** person or thing. So, yes, your sentences mean the same thing (the pair ones, I mean). Just remember that when you decide to use *one* instead of *a/an*, it may sound like you do it on purpose, perhaps, to put a special emphasis on the number. Compare:

> Can I have **a** hamburger? (there is no emphasis on the number of hamburgers + you may mean any kind of hamburger)
>
> Can I have **one** hamburger? (one, and not two or three)

Comment: You haven’t addressed the “yes I got it” part of the question.

Comment: And then there's "I've got it!!", shouted on a baseball field.